Does the existence of an irrational supremum of a sequence of rationals numbers necessarily imply that it is convergent?
Got this from an exercise from Axler's MIRA supplementary text, or at least i hope to have made an equivalent statement. The original question goes as follows:

Prove or give a counterexample: Suppose $a_1, a_2, a_3, . . .$ is a sequence of rational
numbers such that
$$
\text{sup}\{a_1, a_2, a_3, . . .\} = \sqrt{2}
$$
Then
$$
\text{sup}\{a_n, a_{n+1}, a_{n+2}, . . .\} =
\sqrt{2}
$$
for every positive integer n.

I have tried and failed to give a counterexample to this, but can't quite intuitively convince myself of the truth of the statement.

Your title is asking a different question from the body of the post.  The condition certainly doesn't imply that the sequence is convergent; consider the sequence 1, 0, 1.4, 0, 1.41, 0, 1.414, 0, ...

I understand now. The existence of a supremum of a sequence of elements of some set X that does not itself belong to X in no way requires that said sequence is convergent. I apologize for the misuse of the terminology.

Proof by contradiction: pick $n$ so that the supremum from $a_n$ onwards is less than $\sqrt{2}$, then the supremum of the whole sequence is whichever is the larger of that and the maximum of the first $n-1$ terms, which is rational, so less than $\sqrt{2}$. Can you complete the argument from these suggestions?

That was very helpful. Thank you so much. Could it be that the proof could be completed through induction?
